# getCellByColumnAndRow unable to retrieve data on merge cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm new on PHPExcel. I just want to know if it's possible to retrieve data from a merge cells using the function `getCellByColumnAndRow()`.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a merge cells using row and column number. I used this:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,1)->getValue()
```

but it doesn't return any value or error, and when I tried to use this:

```
excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue()
```

It returns the value. What's the solution?

Cells A1 to D1 were merge in my Excel file.

Comment: You always need to reference the cell in the top-left position in the merge group

Answer (score 1):

I Already found the solution. Index column number starts at 0 and not 1.

So if you want to get the value of cell A1 then the code should be:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,1)->getValue()
```

Thank you.